# How to replace the first and the last occurrences in a string

Tags: ruby, regex, match

I have a long string which contains several urls coded in BBcode. For example, part of my string:

```
"...[url=http://example1.com][img]http://picture.com/1.jpg[/img][/url]
[url=http://example2.com][img]http://picture.com/2.jpg[/img][/url]
[url=http://example3.com][img]http://picture.com/3.jpg[/img][/url]..."
```

contains lines before and after `"..."`, but no more lines containing `"[url="` and `"[/url]"`. I want to replace the first occurrence of `"[url="` with `"[spoiler][url=]"` and the last occurrence of `"[/url]"` with `"[/url][/spoiler]"` to obtain this:

```
"...[spoiler][url=http://example1.com][img]http://picture.com/1.jpg[/img][/url]
[url=http://example2.com][img]http://picture.com/2.jpg[/img][/url]
[url=http://example3.com][img]http://picture.com/3.jpg[/img][/url][/spoiler]..."
```

How can I achieve this with Ruby?

Comment: I haven't thought about the regular expression yet, but do you control the building of this string? It'd be easier to just insert those spoiler pieces in the string when it is first built up.

Comment: No, I have no control, I just have a lot of similar strings which I have to "spoilerize".

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
str = str.sub(/\[url=.+\[\/url\]/m, '[spoiler]\0[/spoiler]')
```

the idea is to replace all the code block between the first `[url..]` and the last `[/url]` (tags included) with itself adding `[spoiler]` before and `[/spoiler]` after in the replacement string.

Since the quantifier `+` is greedy the substring `[/url]` must be the last.